# Python and Django TimeZone Format Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a line of code here that works on my dev server for Django and Python using SQL Lite, however when I upload my code it gives me an error about my time zone . Here is my Code. Postgres doesn't like the %z at the end , however SQL Lite its fine. What do I do to fix this on my Heroku Postgres Production Environment? Thanks

```
new_event.start = datetime.strptime(str(obj.start_date) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

Error Message: time data '2020-10-08 12:17:51-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: Python is having an issue with the '-04:00` and `%z` as it has a colon in it. This has actually changed in Python 3.7:  `datetime.strptime('2020-10-08 12:17:51-04:00' ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')                                                                                                     
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 8, 12, 17, 51,tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))`

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway? You are taking a Python datetime and creating another datetime.

Comment: Im using the O365 package and it connects to office 365 via API, and im using it to post calendar events. So you have to have a start and end date . So what's my solution for this ?

Comment: Yeah, but the end result  is you are have `new_event.start` = a datetime. So why not just: `new_event.start=obj.start_date`? It gets you the same result.

Comment: This is true, there was a reason why i did this. Im going to try it and see if it resolves it.

Comment: I'm going to guess because SQLite does not have `date/time` types. Everything is stored as string.

Comment: Genius, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: For the record what worked, `new_event.start=obj.start_date` or the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a good reason to get back where you started:

```
dt                                                                                                                                                                        
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 8, 9, 33, 37, 216144, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=-420, name=None))

datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')                                                                                                                              
'2020-10-08 09:33:37-0700'

dt_2 = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z') 

dt_2
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 8, 9, 33, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200)))
```

This makes the string returned from the datetime object be formatted with a time zone offset that does not have a colon. This means that `strptime` in Python < 3.7 can deal with it.